# How to migrate ADO Boards from one organization to another organization?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-boards

I'm trying to migrate Azure Boards from one organization to another. I dont see any documentation from MS for org to org migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Hugh Lin-MSFT for providing the details. Re-iterating here for broader audience.

If you are referring to moving work items from one organization to another, you can use the Excel to export and import the work items to achieve this .

First, you need to create a query to get work items, then install the Azure DevOps Office Integration Tool in azure devops , in Excel click on the Team button and then New List to get data from Azure DevOps to Excel, and finally publish work items to destination organization.

For detailed steps, please refer to this [blog](https://medium.com/medialesson/move-azure-devops-work-items-from-one-organization-to-another-42ad8370e46b).

In addition, another way is that you could think about using third party extension tool like the [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration#overview) . You can refer to this similar [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/513736/trying-to-move-boards-from-one-project-in-a-organi.html).

Hope this information helps.

Comment: Hi Monika,

Thanks for your response. I have tried migrating through Excel but the problem is you cannot migrate comments and attachments. I have to look into this third party tool.